# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I`m learn the javascript code from the net resource，but I met some problem,
my code isnt working and I am getting an'Uncaught TypeError...'.I hava try many way to resovle the error,but it cannot work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>win下载 </title>
    <style>
        div {width: 200px;height: 200px;float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;margin: 10px}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload=function () {
            var aDiv = document.getElementById('div');
            alert(aDiv.length);
         //   aDiv[0].style.background = 'red';
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no elements with the ID "div"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are using `document.getElementById('div')`. There are no elements with the ID `div`.

I'm assuming you are looking for `document.getElementsByTagName('div')`, which will return all `<div>` elements.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var divElements = document.getElementByTagName('div');

    alert(divElements.length); // 4

    divElements[0].style.background = 'red'; // set the first div element's background to red
};
```

Comment: pretty sure that's what he's looking for, based on his indexing aDiv and checking for length

Comment: @GalenChen no problem, please mark the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

`var aDiv = document.getElementById('div');`
should be
`var aDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');`

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>win下载 </title>
    <style>
        div {width: 200px;height: 200px;float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;margin: 10px}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload=function () {
            var aDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            alert(aDiv.length);
         //   aDiv[0].style.background = 'red';
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(note: it's best to have your JavaScript separate from your html)

Answer (score 1):

Id is an attribute that you give to any HTML tag. eg. `<div id="myFirstDiv">`. It should be unique in the document, and should generally be a meaningful name.

"div" is a tag name, so you could get all your divs in your sample with `getElementsByTagName("div");` and then loop through them.